# Trying to access a function in a vector of classes w/o changing the private-status of the vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am trying to find a way to make the following piece of code work, WITHOUT changing the access of the betasAlphaVector from private to public. Perhaps a function that returns a pointer to the element of a selected element, that can then work? I don't know. Stymied and frustrated. Help, please?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Alpha {

private:
    int anInt;

public:

    Alpha(int arg) { anInt = arg; }

    Alpha(const Alpha& orig) { }

    virtual ~Alpha() { }

    void Printf() { printf("%s: anInt = %d\n", __func__, anInt); }

};

class Beta {

private:    // Can not change protection (private) status of betasAlphaVector
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Alpha>> betasAlphaVector;
public:
    int maxAlphas;

public:

    Beta(int arg) { maxAlphas = arg; }

    Beta(const Beta& orig) { }

    virtual ~Beta() { }

    void AddAlpha(int arg) { betasAlphaVector.emplace_back(new Alpha(arg)); }

    int SizeAlpha() { return (int) betasAlphaVector.size(); }

};

#define MaximumAlphas 3

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Beta *beta = new Beta(MaximumAlphas);

    for (int i = 0; i < beta->maxAlphas; i++)
        beta->AddAlpha(i*10);

    printf("%s: Alpha vector size = %d\n", __func__, beta->SizeAlpha());

    beta->betasAlphaVector.at(1)->Printf();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One suggestion: Make `Beta::SizeAlpha()` return a value of type `size_t` because this is the return type of `std::vector::size()`. This is usually an unsigned integer, because the size can never be less than zero. It also ports better to 64-bit programs because `size_t` will usually map to a 64-bit unsigned integer then, whereas `int` stays 32-bit (on most platforms).

Comment: Too funny; I sent this problem to a group at work. I had size_t as the return data type, as you suggested and they all complained. So, I posted it this way. I agree with you. Never listen to your friends.

Comment: I wonder how they argued?

Comment: Personal preferences and a need to argue about something I guess. I generally, where possible, try to use ssize_t and size_t for exactly the same reasons you specified. Thanks, and thank you for not calling me out as an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

You almost gave the answer:

> Perhaps a function that returns a pointer to the element of a selected
>   element, that can then work

Turning that into code (your other code omitted for brevity):

```
class Beta {
public:
    Alpha* GetAlpha( int index ) { return betasAlphaVector.at( index  ).get(); }
    const Alpha* GetAlpha( int index ) const { return betasAlphaVector.at( index ).get(); }
};
```

The second overload enables you to call the `GetAlpha()` method even when the `Beta` object is declared as `const`.

In `main()`:

```
beta->GetAlpha( 1 )->Printf();
```